# How to work out execution time and real time of algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, real-time

How do you work out the real world time and the execution time of a program using clock()??

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to determine how long it takes a piece of code to run?

Comment: yes i am, i need to know how to work out the real world time it takes for my code to run

Comment: Given that any of the time sources the computer has can be tampered with, you pretty much cannot do this reliably. You can receive a rough estimate by capturing system time right before launching the calculation and right after it finishes, and subtracting the first from the last.

Comment: Which OS do you plan to use? Win32 and POSIX APIs are quite different...

Comment: under unix, you can 'time' your executable, which gives you a rough estmation of different elapsed times. (so get the source for the time utility and peek into it)

Answer (score 0):

if clock() is a requirement, i cannot help. If the "getting the execution time"-part is what you want, you may take a look at the profiling option of the gcc (gnu compiler). You will link your code to specifically compiled libraries, which provide profiling informations.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a good idea to use clock() to find the execution time of a program.

But I can suggest one possible solution to your problem. You have to measure the time using clock() before and after every C statement that sends a running process to a waiting state or blocked state. For example your program might be waiting for a child process to terminate or blocked until the user inputs some data. So on such occasions your program is not utilizing the CPU. So you have to deduct this time from the total running time of your program.

```
int sum,n1,n2;
clock_t t1, t2, t3, t4;
long int x;
double dur1,dur2;

t1 = clock();

printf("\nEnter two numbers:\n");

t2 = clock();

scanf("%d%d",&n1,&n2);

t3 = clock();

sum= n1 + n2;

printf("\nSum is %d\n",sum);

t4 = clock();

dur1 = ( double ) ( t4 - t1 ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

dur2 = ( double ) ( ( t4 - t1 ) - ( t3 - t2 ) ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

printf( "\nThe Total Running time of the proces is %lf\n", dur1 ); 
printf( "\nThe CPU time taken by the proces is %lf\n", dur2 );
```

Of course this program will give only a rough estimate in case of an arbitrarily large program. For small programs the estimate is not all useful.